# How to trigger text-change with QuillJS

Tags: quill

I would like to listen for text change in my quill editor.
Before, it was a regular `text_area` so 
    `MyField.change(function(){ 
    console.log('change!') 
})`

worked fine.

For quill, I saw on the [doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPMdS.png) that I should use `text-change` function.

But nothing happen when I changed the text inside Quill.

```
var $div = $('<div class="editor">');
var $editor = new Quill($div[0]);
$div.data('quill', $editor);


$editor.on('text-change', function() {
  console.log('change!')
})
```

**HTML**

[image]

Comment: I've tested your code and is looking fine (see this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MatheusCuba/h6coee7w/2/)), post your full Js code in the question ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try this it works fine 
**HTML** 
`<div id="editor" </div>`

**JS**

```
var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
  modules: {
    toolbar: true
  },
  placeholder: 'Compose an epic...',
  theme: 'snow'
});

quill.on('text-change', function(delta, source) {
       console.log('text changed');
});
```